# Post в Abo.CMS

Tags: php

Возникает проблема с post'ом в Abo.CMS. Есть такой код в модуле:

```
case "useredit":
    if (!$permissions["e"]) $main->message_access_denied($this->module_name, $action);
    global $request_id, $request_step;
    $main->include_main_blocks_2($this->module_name."_useradd.html", $this->tpl_path);
    $tpl->prepare();
    if(!$request_step || $request_step == 1){
        $user = $this->getUser($request_id);
        $user['id'] = (int) $user['id'];
        $user['form_action'] = $baseurl . '&action=useredit&step=2';
        $user['photolink'] = '' . $user['photo'];
        $tpl->assign($user);
        if($user['photo']){
            $tpl->newBlock('block_photo_exists');
            $tpl->assign($user);
        }
    }
    elseif($request_step == 2){

    }
    break;
```

При `$request_step = 1` все нормально отрабатывает и отображает форму редактирования (`method = post`, `action` содержит `'action=useredit&step=2'`). Но при `$request_step = 2` выкидывает ошибку запроса к базе данных. Если же не отправлять форму, а вбить вручную `&step=2`, то все работает. По моему разумению, ошибка возникает при отправке данных post'ом, но я, хоть убей, не пойму, какой запрос к БД тут может порождать ошибку. Если кто знает особенности Abo.CMS, помогите, пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка найдена, к сожалению, выложенный код тут ни при чем. В шаблоне стояло поле

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{name}">
```

Как оказалось, `name="name"` убивает какую-то внутреннюю логику CMS. Видимо, и `$_GET['name']`, и `$_POST['name']` переводятся в `$request_name`, а потом происходит поиск по БД на предмет модуля с названием `$request_name`. Другого объяснения я найти не могу.

Answer (score 1):

С Abo.CMS не знаком, но глядя на код - мне думается, что может стоит выйти за рамки приведенного кода? Попытаться понять что происходит за его пределами — скорее всего есть какая-то еще логика, которая реагирует на отправленный POST запрос.
Исходя из приведенного кода тяжело представить ошибку к базе, т.к. у нас в принципе ничего не выполняется при $request_step = 2

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что, если что-то выполняется вне этого кода, то оно должно выполняться и при `$request_step = 1`. Походу, Abo реагирует вообще на post.

Comment: как я понимаю при $request_step = 1 выполняется компиляция шаблона $tpl->assign($user);
Может если этого не происходит ($request_step = 2), то обработка POST данных происходит где-то в другом месте?

Comment: Можно решить проблему дедуктивно) В elseif($request_step == 2){ написать exit; и посмотреть — если ошибка базы будет, то значит "вверху" что-то мешает, если будет, допустим, белый экран - значит POST данные "ползут" ниже, и попадают не туда куда нужно.

Comment: В таких случаях я активно применяю метод тыка, сори за не очень профессиональный совет.

Comment: > обработка POST данных происходит где-то в другом месте  
Вот смахивает на то. Тыкал так: `elseif($request_step == 2){die(), ничего не происходило. Поэтому я и спрашиваю об особенностях Abo.